# Salvar dados de um input offline

Tags: angular, ionic

Boa tarde, estou tentando salvar os dados (com o LocalStorage) de um input em uma variável, porém não estou conseguindo da maneira correta. A página em si se trata de uma opção para Salvar dados do usuário.

Segue o .html

```
   <ion-item>
     <ion-label position="Fixed">Nome</ion-label>
     <ion-input [(ngModel)]="nome">{{nome1}}</ion-input>
   </ion-item>
 <ion-button expand="block" (click)="saveInformations()">Salvar</ion-button>
```

Segue o .ts

```
  nome : string; 
  nome1: string;

  saveInformations(){

    localStorage.setItem('nome', this.nome);

    this.nome1 = this.nome

  }


ngOnInit() {

    localStorage.getItem(this.nome)
  }
```

Quando eu saio da página e volto o input aparece em branco, o que estou fazendo de errado?

Comment: Ué, mas e o **getItem('nome')** ???

Comment: Opa, esqueci de botar o código inteiro, já editei.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O valor do input foi salvo no `localStorage` mas você não está lendo e preenchendo seu input com este valor quando seu componente é inicializado.

Exemplo:

```
nome : string; 
nome1: string;

ngOnInit() {
    this.nome1 = localStorage.getItem('nome') || '';
}

saveInformations() {
    localStorage.setItem('nome', this.nome);
    this.nome1 = this.nome
}
```

Comment: Desta maneira até funciona, porém os campos que não foram preenchidos, aparece undefined

Comment: Consegui resolver desta forma ` if (this.nome == undefined ){
      this.nome1 =  ''
    } else {
      localStorage.getItem('nome');
    }` porém no html ele repete o input duas vezes, consegue me ajudar neste caso?

Comment: @rzp Dá para retirar a variável `nome1` e usar apenas a `nome`. Altere o componente para:  `<ion-input [(ngModel)]="nome"></ion-input>` e ajuste no `ngOnInit` para preencher a variável `nome` ao invés de `nome1`. Isto deve funcionar. Se não funcionar é só falar ;) abs